# Territories in a C++ Risk Clone

Tags: c++

For fun, I've been programming a Risk clone in C++ and I need some help with the territories/Continents part of it. Setting them up so that they know what territories are adjacent to them, what Continent it is apart of, who currently controls it and of course the amount of armies currently in it.

Likewise, the Continent needs to know all the territories that are in it, so a player who controls the whole Continent gets corresponding reinforcement bonus for that Continent.

Currently, I think a using `std::set` may be the best choice, but I need some suggestions on how to set it up.

Comment: What do you mean, "set it up"? `std::set<MyType> x;`.

Comment: Sounds like a typically good question to ask over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `std::set` is optimized for fast insert/delete/lookup by value.  You're probably better of with `std::vector>`.

Comment: You might want to look up "adjacency matrix". It's a simple way to indicate adjacency between territories/continents. An adjacency matrix is how you could implement Mazen's solution for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Create a graph where each Territory object has an array (vector/whatever) of other territories it is adjacent to. Then have a Continent object for each continent which has a list of territories that are in it.

At end of each turn check to see that all territories in a continent all belong to the same player and if so give that player the extra resources defined by the continent. The territories themselves will be updated after each fight in a turn.

an `std::vector` should be more than sufficient, no need to complicate things.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using the [boost graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) library to make the country graph.  A `std::map` could then take countries to continents, or a `std::multimap` to go the other direction.